# UNION SELECT with dummy data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to create a limit of 6 rows with this logic:

1. Select user_id's that are in the friends list (and also in the same table)
2. if there are less that 6, select then another RANDOM users,but not in friends list (until limit of 6)
3. if there are not 6 user_id's, add some "dummy" users id (with id 0)
4. all "real" users must be distinct (with id > 0)

   ```
   id | friends_list | name
   1    2,3,5          John
   2    1,7,9          Michael
   3    1,2,5          Tom
   4    3,2,6          Larry
   ```

The expected result must be something like this `(for a given user e.g. id=1)`:

`2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0`

Comment: What database are you using? Wait. Are you seriously storing someone's friend list as a comma separated value in their record?

Comment: Yes, with comma and I`m using mysql

Comment: Why don't you normalize your data?

Comment: UPDATE: friendslist is not in my table. i received the list from an array and I think it`s ok. I tried somethign like this:                                                                 SELECT id from table where id in (friends list IDs that I got from a script with comma separated) LIMIT 6

Comment: Sorry, SQL doesn't work like that. You can't use `IN` to search in a comma separated string. You need to learn about normalization before you shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably store your data differently and use joins to select the data out of multiple tables.  There are also other ways you might think about storing data also depending on your use cases.

```
PEOPLE TABLE
id | name
1  | John
2  | Michael
3  | Tom
4  | Larry

PEOPLE_FRIENDS TABLE
id | person_id | friend_id
1  | 1         | 2          //In this case John is friends with Michael
2  | 3         | 1          //In this case Tom is friends with John.
```

The following select would pull id's for John's friends.

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE `P` INNER JOIN PEOPLE_FRIENDS `PF` ON P.id = P.person_id WHERE P.id = 1
```

Again a million different ways to go about writing that query as well, but this will get you pointed in the right direction I think.

Comment: I gotcha! But how can I add N dummy rows until limit of N?

Comment: You simply add as many rows as you need in the PEOPLE_FRIENDS table, unless I'm not understanding your question properly.